# SQLAlchemy query tuple values

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, tuples, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to display the output of an SQLAlchemy query into a jinja template.
My query is as follows:

```
query = db.session.query(models.Server, models.Scan).outerjoin(models.Server.scans).all()
```

The output of which is:

```
[(<Server u'Testing'>, <Scan u'testscan'>), (<Server u'fasd'>, <Scan u'testscan'>), (<Server u'fdaafas'>, None)]
```

The Server table contains three columns: `name, description and ip`.
The Scan table contrain anothe three columns: `type, scan_id and timestamp`.

What I am trying to do is access the servers description and corresponding scan_type.
I have tried making the query a dict but still cannot access the relevant values. Any help would be great!

Comment: Show your jinja template please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a join in SQLAlchemy, at least in the case where you specify models as your select, each record gets returned as a tuple of the joined model objects.  What you have is a list of tuples of Server and Scan objects.  `query[i]` yields a tuple, `query[i][0]` yields a Server object, and `query[i][1]` yields a Scan object.  All you have to do is `query[i][0].description` to get the server description and `query[i][1].type` to get the scan type.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!